# Getting the name of the form that opened a new form

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a search window in a Delphi7 application that needs to behave differently depending on which form was Active when the search was opened. Specifically, there are two forms that need to have a different button visible on the search, when it should be invisible when coming from all other forms.

Is there a way to access the property that stores the name of a form (either accessing the Name property or even the Caption property) that I can send as a parameter? Or another better/cleaner way of achieving this, if you know of one.

Comment: Why don't you pass a parameter to a method of the form?

Comment: The search button is from a menu on the mainForm, not as a button on each individual form. I'd like to do just that, but I need to know the name of the active form before I can pass it.

Comment: The secondary form is simply shown or is it shown modal?

Comment: Well, `Screen.ActiveForm` is the currently active form. But perhaps you main form will always be active if the action is invoked from a menu.

Comment: Are you dealing with a MDI application? Multi-window? Tell us what a "mainForm" and what "other forms" are.

Comment: MDI - the 'mainForm' contains a menu for opening the other forms in the application. And the forms are not modal, users can have multiple open and switch between them.

Comment: ActiveMDIChild IIRC should give you the currently active Child Form in an MDI application. If not, then the name is something close to that.

Comment: @Marjan That's exactly the right name. Please do make it an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an MDI application, the main form's `ActiveMDIChild` property gives you the currently active child form.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is

In one of form

```
procedure TFormMain.btnSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   TFormSearch.CallForm(self); 
end;
```

In another form:

```
procedure TFormMain2.btnSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   TFormSearch.CallForm(self); 
end;
```

And other:

```
procedure TFormMain3.btnSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   TFormSearch.CallForm(self); 
end;
```

In TFormSearch source code u may get the name of the form that opened in onshow event

```
class procedure TFormSearch.CallForm(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
   with TFormSearch.Create(AOwner) do
   begin
      showmodal;
      free;
   end;
end;

procedure TFormSearch.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Showmessage(Owner.ClassName);
end;
```

You will need to remove TFormSearch from list of auto-create form in Project->Option->Forms

I hope it has helped you

Comment: You mean `Self` rather than `this`. But even so, your code shows 'TFormMain' every single time. I don't think you quite understood the question.

Comment: showmessage is only to show that you can take the name of the form that called TFormsearch, you don't need keep showmessage it in your code, take the name and store in a var to do what you want to customise the form in this case

Comment: I have no trouble at all understanding what `ShowMessage` does. Read my comment again. Point 1, your code is not Delphi. There is no `this`. That's C++, Java, C# etc. Point 2, your code doesn't do what the question asks. The question asks about runtime state. But your code produces the string `'TFormMain'` which is known at compile time.

Comment: Thanks, I improve the answer to aid in understanding, point 1 was mistype and point 2 was not clear in my answer